# How to write text on image in windows store app development? C#,wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, windows-store-apps

I have search so much on this topic and I couldn't find a way to draw a text on image or even a create an image and then draw a text in windows store app.

Is there way to load image from `ms-appx:///Assets/image.png` and write a text on the center of the image that passes somehow and save it into `ms-appdata:///roaming/image11.png`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `RenderTargetBitmap` - this article has a pretty good explanation for Windows Store apps: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20648.using-the-rendertargetbitmap-in-windows-store-apps-with-xaml-and-c.aspx.

If you meant WPF, it's similar: http://wpftutorial.net/BitmapFromVisual.html (just create a image control with textbox for the `Visual`)

Comment: Thankx for your reply and links bro.. I have read those links. RenderTargetBitmap used for UIElement rights. I am not using a UIElement in here. I have set of aplications list saved db using application class. In that there is a appName and Logo as properties.Actually scenario is load an image from Assest in current application folder then write a text on center of the image which text is passed from db(appName) and save that image in roaming folder. Then inside view  <Image Source="{Binding Application.Logo}" /> will bind the string value path of roaming folder which we saved previously.

Comment: You should be able to create a temporary UIElement, something like an <Grid><Image/><TextBox/></Grid>, and set the Image source to the logo, TextBox.Text to the text that you want to write, and then use RenderTargetBitmap to render that whole Grid to an image, and save it to the roaming folder.